# Statistical mechanics with multiple species

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

How do we derive the equivalent of the Boltzmann distribution when there are multiple species in equilibrium?

I'm thinking of situations where there are multiple species of particle involved, and they can change back-and-forth. The specific example I am considering is neutron star material where various exotic particles start to be important because the thermal energy levels get filled up to the point that things like baryon resonances start to get produced. But I'm also thinking about just regular chemical processes where various species of molecule can interact and switch back-and-forth.

I'm thinking about such things as using the distribution function to derive an equation of state and such-like. But I'm really getting confused over such things as the relative rate of production of various species as a function of temperature.

Comment: Are you sure that taking the grand canonical distribution (instead of the canonical, with Boltzmann distribution) is not enough? The "rates of production" can be taken into consideration in equilibrium thermodynamics (the only robust thermodynamics that exists) only if they eventually give rise to equilibria, with equilibrium constants that can be translated into differences of chemical potential.

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli you're right, the question is a bit vague and I got confused. This answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/545821/226902 (in the canonical formalism) provides a line guide that can be easily generalized to the multi-species case (as long as the particles just scatter but do not react). In the reacting case, you're right that the grand canonical is more appropriate. Hence, I deleted my misleading initial comment.

Comment: But I am also confused. I suggest @Boba Fit to clarify the relation between his question and the grand canonical approach. If the total number of particles is fixed, then the grand canonical approach should not rigorously work, although, sometimes, we just  play with the chemical potentials until we get an "average number of particles" that suits what we want, and is probably the requested result.